# 2005 Ford Explorer check engine cod P0446

Tags: ford, repair, diagnostics, explorer, p0446

I have a 2005 Ford Explorer that has a check engine code P0446 which reads as Evap container system vent check malfunction. How do I repair this and where do I start?

Answer (score -2):

Unless you care about federal Emission laws or live somewhere that do emissions test its unnecessary spending

[image]